# SQL Server - matching attributes query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, bit-manipulation

SQL Server Gurus ...

Currently using MS SQL Server 2016

I know Joe Celko and all SQL purists are squirming at the thought of using bitmasks, but I have a use case in which I need to query for all widgets that contain a set of given attributes.

- Each widget may contain several hundred attributes.
- The attributes of a widget are either present or not (1 = present, 0 = not 
  present)

One way I thought to do this is via bitmasks – the attributes to be found (a bitmask) could be ANDed with the attributes of each widget to find matches in a single operation.  For example, the widgets table might be:

```
widets table:
widget_uid  Uniqueidentifier
attributes  BigInt

SELECT widget_uid
   FROM widgets
  WHERE ( attributes & bitmask ) = bitmask;
```

Problem is, using a BigInt for the attributes limits the number of attributes to 64 (a widget can have several hundred attributes), I could group the attributes in chunks of 64 bits, ie:

```
widets table:
widget_uid  Uniqueidentifier
attributes0 BigInt   -- Attributes 0-63
attributes1 BigInt   -- Attributes 64-127
attributes2 BigInt   -- Attributes 128-191

SELECT widget_uid
   FROM widgets
  WHERE ( attributes0 & bitmask0 ) = bitmask0
    AND ( attributes1 & bitmask1 ) = bitmask1
    AND ( attributes2 & bitmask2 ) = bitmask2
```

... but was wondering if anyone has come up with a solution for bit operations using bitmasks with greater than 64 bits – or if other (more efficient?) solutions would exist?

In the use case, the widgets table does contain other columns, but I am only concerned with the attributes matching portion of the query at the moment.

Any and all ideas are welcome - would be interested in knowing how others tackle this particular problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ideas?  Don't use bitmasks.  Use junction/associations tables, which SQL was designed to use.

Comment: Thanks - I assume that would require 100+ "associated" tables and I can't imagine the size of the dynamic SQL query that would be required -- any examples you can point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar use case, on a significantly large data set. This was for an e-commerce site with products and attributes.  Our case was a bit more complex than here, where we had any possible number of attributes and then values assigned to those attributes. e.g. Color - Red/Green/Blue, Size - S/M/L etc.

We found that associated tables with good indexing was the key in our case. While this may not be an option for you we found this to be the optimal solution for a dynamic data set.

I can code you up an example if you feel it will be helpful.

Edited to add example:
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Widgets
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Attributes
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #WidgetAttributes

```
CREATE TABLE #Widgets (widget_UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Name NVARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #Attributes  (Attribute_UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Name NVARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #WidgetAttributes (widget_UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,Attribute_UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_WidgetAttribute ON #WidgetAttributes (Attribute_UID) INCLUDE (widget_UID)

INSERT INTO #Widgets (widget_UID, Name) values
( '{c63bea73-2331-4698-82c9-f71845ab8601}', N'Widget 1' ), 
( '{a0865b8f-606b-4273-9207-39a8a26016c4}', N'Widget 2' ), 
( '{211fe27e-ab98-4b61-83a3-3d006d66db5a}', N'Widget 3' )

INSERT INTO #Attributes (Attribute_UID, Name)
VALUES
( '{99354dc0-d0b2-4919-a887-edf115eeb1bd}', N'Height' ), 
( '{136bbe4c-497d-472f-a905-670e4a7805d0}', N'Width' ), 
( '{f006f950-30d1-453e-8e09-4f7d140fa3cb}', N'Depth' ), 
( '{0d190639-677f-4b75-8d36-1bdac00de132}', N'Colour' )

-- Set links
-- Widget 1 All attributes
-- Widget 2 Height Width 
-- Widget 3 Colour

INSERT INTO #WidgetAttributes (widget_UID, Attribute_UID)
SELECT  '{c63bea73-2331-4698-82c9-f71845ab8601}',Attribute_UID FROM #Attributes
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (2) '{a0865b8f-606b-4273-9207-39a8a26016c4}',Attribute_UID FROM #Attributes WHERE Name<> 'Colour'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '{211fe27e-ab98-4b61-83a3-3d006d66db5a}',Attribute_UID FROM #Attributes WHERE Name = 'Colour'

-- @SearchAttributes to hold list of attributes you are trying to find
DECLARE @SearchAttributes TABLE (Attribute_UID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO @SearchAttributes
SELECT Attribute_UID FROM #Attributes WHERE Name<> 'Colour'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT WA.widget_UID, COUNT(1) AttributesPresent FROM #WidgetAttributes WA
JOIN @SearchAttributes SA ON SA.Attribute_UID = WA.Attribute_UID
GROUP BY WA.widget_UID
)
SELECT cte.AttributesPresent
     , W.widget_UID
     , W.Name 
FROM cte 
JOIN #Widgets W ON W.widget_UID = cte.widget_UID
ORDER BY cte.AttributesPresent DESC
```

Gives an output of:

```
AttributesPresent widget_UID                           Name
----------------- ------------------------------------ ----------
3                 C63BEA73-2331-4698-82C9-F71845AB8601 Widget 1
2                 A0865B8F-606B-4273-9207-39A8A26016C4 Widget 2
```

We used an approach of counting how many attributes were present for each so we not only had the option of "exact match" but also "closest fit".

Comment: Sure -- share an example or point to one if available -- would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using bitmask in databases is wrong approach. Even if you somewhow manage it to work, you will not be able to use indexes to speed up execution.

Use standard solution, this is standard situation. There is standard M:N relationship between Widgets and Attributes (both should be tables, of course). You will add another table that will assign Attributes to Widgets - you can call it WidgetAttributes.

It will have 3 columns: Id, WidgetId, AttributeId

Then you can simply for example get list of Widgets that have Attribute:

```
select w.* 
    from Widgets w
    inner join WidgetAttributes wa on wa.WidgetId = w.Id
    inner join Attributes a on a.Id = wa.AttributeId
    where a.AttributeName='xxx'
```